# Can my Wordpress website show two scripts side by side

Tags: javascript, wordpress

We have a Wordpress website and have used widgets from another party. We are trying to make these display side by side using the widget areas. The issue is the page will only show one. It forces the first to not appear.

We have tried using in completely different rows, tabs, using code blocks as opposed to widget areas etc but no matter what we try it will only show one.

and

We expected as these were code supplied by the 3rd party and preview works fine their end, that they would simply need putting into widget areas.

We are wondering if its a limitation our end or just something that wont work.

Comment: <div id="inform-widget">
<script src="https://inform.dataloft.co.uk/widgets/stats/BAh7CEkiCGdpZAY6BkVUSSIrZ2lkOi8vaW5mb3JtL1VzZXJBcmVhLzEwMzI1P2V4cGlyZXNfaW4GOwBUSSIMcHVycG9zZQY7AFRJIgxkZWZhdWx0BjsAVEkiD2V4cGlyZXNfYXQGOwBUMA==--a2d16d1c614f4ce55c3884d948d2ee74e69edf49/-RjPEjRmpswiga2liLwhnw/js"></script>
</div>

Comment: <div id="inform-widget">
 <script src="https://inform.dataloft.co.uk/widgets/stats/BAh7CEkiCGdpZAY6BkVUSSIrZ2lkOi8vaW5mb3JtL1VzZXJBcmVhLzEwMjA3P2V4cGlyZXNfaW4GOwBUSSIMcHVycG9zZQY7AFRJIgxkZWZhdWx0BjsAVEkiD2V4cGlyZXNfYXQGOwBUMA==--622c854c357d1a4d888a03256cc92e68cb4c368c/-RjPEjRmpswiga2liLwhnw/js"></script>
 </div>

Comment: Had to add the two pieces of code as comments

Comment: When adding information, please edit your question instead of writing it as comment

Comment: @Hasta - I tried many times as I explained - it refuses to show the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that the culprit is the third-party code. In the JS that is loaded, it uses `document.getElementById("inform-widget")` and then sets the HTML of that element to the content from their server. Because it doesn't check if there are more than one element with the ID of "inform-widget" (and frankly, there shouldn't be, since IDs are supposed to be unique), what happens is it just keeps replacing the content of the very first `<div id="inform-widget">`. The best solution would be for the third party to either allow for multiple widgets by switching to targeting widgets by class, or by providing some sort of dynamic embed code or iframe src URL.

A workaround that you could use yourself, is to manually throw each widget script + div into an iframe. So, for example, you could upload a very simple HTML file to your server at example.com/inform-widget-1.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Widget</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="inform-widget"></div>
    <script src="https://inform.dataloft.co.uk/widgets/stats/..."></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And then replace the widget code in Wordpress with `<iframe src="/inform-widget-1.html"></iframe>`. You could have as many widgets as you want on one page with this method, and they should all work together without issue.

Another option is to auto-generate the same iframe embeds above, with PHP, so you don't have to manually upload an HTML file for each widget. That is beyond the scope of this question, but would be pretty easy for someone comfortable with PHP.

Comment: Thank you so much this worked a treat! Much obliged.